# How to capture payment gateway transactions in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to capture Razorpay payment gateway transactions in Google Sheets using webhook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, after you profided the JSON i understand the structure. As you can see in your json you need to dig into the json to get the amount. Like this:

```
const dig = myData.payload.payment.entity;
const amount = dig.amount
```

So if you want the bank_transaction_id you will get it with:

```
const bankTransferId = dig.acquirer_data.bank_transaction_id;
```

I hope this makes sense? As you can see is posted the awnser and a test function so you can try and test for yourself, with the console log you can check your work. In the screenshot you see the debugger, there you can see the JSON tree ;)

[image]

**SOLUION:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

function doPost(e) {
  const params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
  const myData = JSON.parse(params);
  const ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "dd/MM/YYYY");
  const dig = myData.payload.payment.entity;
  const row = [ts,params,myData.id,dig.amount,dig.status,dig.method,dig.vpa,dig.email,dig.contact];
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data")
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
};
```

**TEST:**

```
function test(){
  const raw =
      {
        "entity": "event",
        "account_id": "acc_BFQ7uQEaa7j2z7",
        "event": "payment.authorized",
        "contains": [
          "payment"
        ],
        "payload": {
          "payment": {
            "entity": {
              "id": "pay_DESlfW9H8K9uqM",
              "entity": "payment",
              "amount": 100,
              "currency": "INR",
              "status": "authorized",
              "order_id": "order_DESlLckIVRkHWj",
              "invoice_id": null,
              "international": false,
              "method": "netbanking",
              "amount_refunded": 0,
              "refund_status": null,
              "captured": false,
              "description": null,
              "card_id": null,
              "bank": "HDFC",
              "wallet": null,
              "vpa": null,
              "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
              "contact": "+919876543210",
              "notes": [],
              "fee": null,
              "tax": null,
              "error_code": null,
              "error_description": null,
              "error_source": null,
              "error_step": null,
              "error_reason": null,
              "acquirer_data": {
                "bank_transaction_id": "0125836177"
              },
              "created_at": 1567674599
            }
          }
        },
        "created_at": 1567674606
      };
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const string = JSON.stringify(raw);
  const myData = JSON.parse(string);
  const dig = myData.payload.payment.entity;
  const ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "dd/MM/YYYY");
  const row = [ts,myData.id,dig.amount,dig.status,dig.method,dig.vpa,dig.email,dig.contact];
  
  console.log(dig.email);
  
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help but the issue is still the same. I'm getting all the data in the same cell only, like the above-attached image.

Comment: At a closer look it seems like you need to dig into the json. Would be nice to post the real text itself, then i can format it to a good readable json to help you out.

Comment: @SumitSingh see my solution above

Comment: After doing some modifications in codes, my issue is resolved. Thank you so much for your help and support.